# BaseX encoding of generated hashs

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

i need to generate hashes from element-values stored in a xml-database managed by BaseX.
Applying a hash-function, eg. hash:md5(value) is returning following String: "|¶﹋¥*PܮQፒ˄|¶﹋¥*PܮQፒ˄" hash:sha1() returning similar nonsense as well.

Have i set the whatever-encoding to utf8 befor? (the XML-database itself is in some human-readable encoding)

Using BaseX 8.4.4

Comment: Interesting -- this is a place where the GUI's behavior has changed for the worse between 8.3.x and 8.4.4; previously, it used the `xs:string` rendering of any `xs:*Binary` datatype out-of-the-box. (I'm not sure that this is a "bug", per se, inasmuch as I'm not aware of any documented guarantee the current behavior violates -- but it's certainly not as user-friendly as it used to be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the explicit documentation for the basex `hash` module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Hashing_Module), results are in `xs:base64Binary` -- which, while it casts to a string as base-64 data, is still binary at its core.

If you want to cast that to a `xs:string` of hex digits:

```
xs:string(xs:hexBinary(hash:md5("hello")))
```

...or, for the default base64 representation returned by `hash:md5()`, again stringified to prevent any return to binary form...

```
xs:string(hash:md5("hello"))
```

Comment: the first is that what you expevted to be a md5-hash. IMO this should be the default return value 0f any baseX-hash-fn. The current default is rather useless...

Comment: I disagree -- a hash value is an innately binary value. The big expanded human-readable forms are for humans; they're needlessly inefficient for machine uses (like hash table lookups), where they reduce the information density and thus make the hash table less uniform in how its slots are filled.

Comment: ...now, to clarify, I agree that it's a bug (well, an undesired behavior -- "bug" means "contrary to documentation") that it's **represented to a human** as a binary value, but it's absolutely not a bug that it's calculated and stored that way under the hood.

Comment: This is due to changed serialization in BaseX (and the behavior as-is is not necessarily wrong, just does not fit the documentation). There is a [bug report discussing similar issues](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1296), I added a note the documentation of the hash functions should be updated. Whenever you use the hash value as a string, it will get serialized as hex digits anyway; but then the documentation must be extended.

Comment: what do you mean with "Whenever you use the hash value as a string, it will get serialized as hex digits anyway"? For what and how can I use a base64binary-typed sequence? Currently I need to compare the hash with another hash.. For this I need 3 casts like "xs:string(xs:hexBinary(hash:sha1(xs:string($toHashElem/text())))) = hash"

Comment: @ArnoJanStaNimus, If you're building something like a crypto algorithm, using the raw binary (padded out into PKCS#1 or a similar format) is essential. And if you're using them for hashing purposes, then -- as discussed before -- it may not be essential, but it's certainly a good idea; the raw binary representation will hash across buckets evenly, whereas using ASCII encoding as hash keys will be very uneven in distribution, so depending on your hash table construction it'll either be a deeper tree than otherwise needed or start bucketing into lists/arrays or such with O(n) traversal.

Comment: @ArnoJanStaNimus, ...this usage pattern has parallels in other languages; if you have a hashlib.md5 instance in Python, you couldn't just compare that object m or the hash algorithm's literal (binary) result m.digest() directly against a hex-encoded string, you'd need to pass that result through binascii.b2a_hex(), or use m.hexdigest() to do that for you.

Comment: You are all right. I just wanted to say that for me, binary type is nothing what i expect at any layer which is directly interacting with the user. In discussed case, XQuery does not even allow binary data as an input (not sure if BaseX allow it other ways) So, i agree it is in every case more efficient to work with those raw data if possible. But yet i can't imagine such a case

Comment: `xs:hexBinary` can absolutely be used for user-provided input -- not just in BaseX, but in anything that supports datatypes defined in the XML schema spec. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#hexBinary -- but I do agree that failing to encode data before exposing it to the user is unfortunate, and hope to see the bug report Jens linked addressed.

Answer (score 4):

With BaseX 8.4, the [serialization method "basex"](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Extensions#Serialization) is now used as default serialization method. As a consequence, items of type xs:base64Binary and xs:hexBinary will now be output in their native binary representation, even in the BaseX GUI.

Changing the output method was the result of repeated discussions on the old "raw" serialization method, and user feedback regarding RESTXQ and other APIs, where people failed to return binary data (e.g. file contents) in its native representation. If you want to have binary data output as hex or base64, you can switch to another output method:

```
declare option output:method 'text';
hash:md5('abc')
```

As Charles Duffy already indicated, you can also use `xs:string()` or `string()` to see the hex or Base64 representation of binary data. Various examples in the documentation have been updated (everyone: feel free to register for our Wiki!).

In terms of performance, comparing binary data will be much faster than comparing string representations. The Hashing Module of BaseX generates items of type xs:base64Binary out of the box (similar to most other standard or extensions functions of XQuery that deal with binary data). However, the XQuery specification does not allow you to directly compare hex and Base64, so you may need to convert hex to Base64 or the other way round. In BaseX (and most other XQuery implementations), this is very cheap, as the internal byte representation is identical. An example:

```
let $hash := '900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72'
let $input := 'abc'
return xs:hexBinary(hash:md5($input)) = xs:hexBinary($hash)
```

With the latest [8.4.4 snapshot](http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/) of BaseX, it is possible to specify nodes as input for the hash functions, so there will be no need anymore to cast elements to strings:

```
let $hash := '900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72'
let $toHashElem := <x>abc</x>
return xs:hexBinary(hash:md5($toHashElem)) = xs:hexBinary($hash)
```